# Odd and Even number using single loop

Tags: javascript

output should be:
1
3
5
7
9
11
etc...
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
etc...

Comment: `const x = Array.from({length:100},(_,$)=>$);x.slice(0,-~x.length/2).forEach((_,$)=>x.push(...x.splice($,1)));`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you need this or not!..

```js
const odd =[];
const even = [];
for (var x=0; x<=15; x++) {
        if (x === 0 || x % 2 === 0) {
                even.push(x);
        } 
        else { 
            odd.push(x);
        }
}
console.log(odd);
console.log(even);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it, but please next time try to solve it by yourself first.

```js
  const n = 100;
  const odd = [];
  const even = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    (i % 2 === 0 ? even : odd).push(i);
  }
  console.log({ odd, even });
```